# php date will not insert into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

this is a strange one.

I have a date, that is converted to `mm-dd-yyyy`
when posting it to mysql i have re-ordered it to `yyyy-mm-dd`
but yet it still will not insert

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['leaving_date']) );
```

any advice?
Cheers

**EDIT**

The actual query:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO booking_info (customer_id, booking_ref, date_of_travel) VALUES (".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['customer_id']).", ".mysql_real_escape_string($rnd).", ".mysql_real_escape_string($date).")");
```

Comment: What error messages are returned?

Comment: no error message, i do have them on, thats the strange thing.
everything else gets populated as it should in the db

Comment: Show your insert query, please.

Comment: Define what "does not insert" means exactly. What is happening and what do you expect instead?

Comment: Can you print out your SQL statement so you can check it looks like you expect? Does it run fine when you paste it directly in the database?

Comment: mysql_query("INSERT INTO booking_info (customer_id, booking_ref, date_of_travel)
VALUES (".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['customer_id']).", ".mysql_real_escape_string($rnd).", ".mysql_real_escape_string($date).")");

Comment: Likely your insert statement is incorrect.  Try echoing out the $date and putting it in the database manually.  That should narrow it down.

Comment: problem is in query not in above php statement.

Comment: Your date must be quoted with single quotes, as well as your customer_id.

Comment: What is the column type? If your column is datetime then you need to add the "time" element to it.

Comment: I would try to add single quotes around the values in your query

Comment: Obviously malformed query is malformed.

Comment: `mysql_query("INSERT INTO booking_info (customer_id, booking_ref, date_of_travel) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['customer_id'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($rnd)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($date)."')");`

Comment: [PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo.php) is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

your values are not wrap with single quotes.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO booking_info (customer_id, booking_ref, date_of_travel) 
             VALUES (
               '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['customer_id'])."',
               '".mysql_real_escape_string($rnd)."', 
               '".mysql_real_escape_string($date)."')");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO booking_info (customer_id, booking_ref, date_of_travel) VALUES (".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['customer_id']).", ".mysql_real_escape_string($rnd).", '$date')");
```

try that one.... should fix the problem but not a good way to write sql... no need to call mysql_real_escape_string function on $date variable as your $date variable.

Answer (score 1):

It should be mentioned that using PDO wouldn't give you these issues; let me illustrate:

```
// assuming $db is a PDO instance to your database
// prepare the statement
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO booking_info (customer_id, booking_ref, date_of_travel) VALUES (:customer, :ref, :date)');
// execute the statement with your variables
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':customer' => $_POST['customer_id'],
    ':ref' => $rnd,
    ':date' => $date,
));
```

The proper quoting and escaping is done in the background; neat huh? :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your editted question, it appears you are lacking single quotes around your date. Also, it may be slower, but you can always have MySQL do the formatting for you. Depending on what extension you are using, you can do something like this:

```
INSERT ... VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('$phpDate', '%m-%d-%Y')), col2, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have single quotes around the date (and possibly the booking_ref if this is not an integer or other sort of numerical field.

Try this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO booking_info (customer_id, booking_ref, date_of_travel) VALUES (".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['customer_id']).", ".mysql_real_escape_string($rnd).", '".mysql_real_escape_string($date)."')");
```

Answer (score -1):

When you're adding a date, wrap it using double quotes, like a string.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO booking_info (customer_id, booking_ref, date_of_travel) VALUES (".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['customer_id']).", ".mysql_real_escape_string($rnd).", \"".mysql_real_escape_string($date)."\")");
```

Comment: Typically most programmers would use single quotes in SQL inserts around dates, varchar, etc.